# GHCI ругается на выражение

Tags: haskell

```
let sumSquareOrSquareSum = let sumSquare = (x^2+y^2)
                               squareSum = (x+y)^2 in
    if squareSum>sumSquare
    then squareSum
    else sumSquare
```

Почему ругается?

Comment: Добавьте текст ошибки в вопрос.

Comment: Приложите сообщение об ошибке.

Answer (score 2):

Я так понимаю, вы пытаетесь определить функцию, в таком случае стоит указать имена ее параметров.

GHCI по умолчанию не поддерживает ввод многострочных команд, но его можно включить с помощью `:set +m`

```hs
Prelude> :set +m
Prelude> let
Prelude|   sumSquareOrSquareSum x y =
Prelude|     let
Prelude|       sumSquare = x^2+y^2
Prelude|       squareSum = (x+y)^2
Prelude|     in
Prelude|       if squareSum > sumSquare
Prelude|         then squareSum
Prelude|         else sumSquare
```

Либо можно взять многострочный код в специальные скобки

```hs
Prelude> :{
Prelude| let
Prelude|   sumSquareOrSquareSum x y =
Prelude|     let
Prelude|       sumSquare = x^2+y^2
Prelude|       squareSum = (x+y)^2
Prelude|     in
Prelude|       if squareSum > sumSquare
Prelude|         then squareSum
Prelude|         else sumSquare
Prelude| :}
```

Конечно можно ввести все в одну строку, но в таком случае синтаксис немного изменится

```hs
Prelude> let sumSquareOrSquareSum x y = let {sumSquare = x^2+y^2; squareSum = (x+y)^2} in if squareSum > sumSquare then squareSum else sumSquare
```

Ну и наверное стоит отметить, что функция получилась излишне детализированной, что только вредит читаемости.

```hs
Prelude> let sumSquareOrSquareSum x y = max (x^2+y^2) ((x+y)^2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понимаю, у Вас проблемы с форматированием текста. В частности, оператора if, но возможно не только. Попробуйте заглянуть [сюда](https://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/ControlStructures)

Comment: писал в одну строку

Comment: @VladimirNeutrino Тогда действительно нужен текст ошибки. У меня есть пара смутных мыслей, но без текста ошибки сложно их довести до уровня ответа.

Answer (score 0):

Код:

```
sumSquareOrSquareSum x y = let sumSquare = (x^2+y^2)
                               squareSum = (x+y)^2 
                              in
                                  if squareSum>sumSquare
                                  then squareSum
                                  else sumSquare

main = do
  print (sumSquareOrSquareSum 10 20)
```

<strike>let здесь не нужен[1]</strike>, а вот указать параметры функции `sumSquareOrSquareSum` - не помешало бы.

P.S. Извините, не обратил внимание, что Вы в ghci работаете.

[1] - если версия ghci >= 8.0.2